# Rendimiento del servidor con NodeJS y MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, rendimiento

Es la primera vez que pregunto, espero la puedan entender.

Realizando un proyecto web me surgió una duda respecto al rendimiento del servidor cuando se le hacen muchas peticiones. Esta es una petición GET que antes de devolverme todos los datos, las ordena modificando la base de datos. La petición se ejecuta siempre que el usuario navegue a cualquier parte de la web. Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo afecta esto al servidor si son muchos usuarios?

Comment: Y qué petición es esa? Cuantas son *muchas* peticiones? Qué problema o error tienes? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta se responde con un gran **depende**, y eso implica una pregunta demasiado amplia y/o basada en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. Saludos

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario! Ahí modifique la pregunta, espero se entienda mejor.

Comment: Como afecta? esa pregunta es demasiado amplia, pero pues a "grosso modo", cada petición que el servidor reciba consume memoria ram y procesador, dependiendo del tipo de servidor y de la máquina sobre la cual esté montada pues tendrá un mejor o peor rendimiento. Pero todo es muy relativo, depende de que tan "pesado" sea procesar esa petición, cuanto tarde el servidor en responder, en que hardware está montado el servidor, cuantos usuarios esperas que estén cargando al mismo tiempo la página, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: No sé del tema, pero creo que una petición GET no debería modificar el estado interno del programa.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Pipe, ahora tengo cierta noción de cómo investigar sobre ese tema.